# wpallimport dont run import based on database value

Tags: php, wordpress, wpallimport

I have set multiple imports with wpallimport running with cron jobs everyday. Is it possible to check a database field and if it exists the import should run otherwise it should be skipped.
So I can handle which imports are active or not via the database.

I was thinking using this filter:

```
function my_is_post_to_update( $continue, $post_id, $xml_node, $import_id ) {
    // Run this code on a specific import
    if ($import_id === 5) {
        // Do something to decide if this post should update
        if ( ... ) {
            return true;
        }
    // Don't update this post 
    return false;
    }
}

add_filter( 'wp_all_import_is_post_to_update', 'my_is_post_to_update', 10, 4 );
```

But the problem is that I have to check a custom_field in each import to get a number which will be used in the query to check if the import should be run or not.

Comment: The filter you mentioned is for an individual post that would get updated by an import. Please clarify whether that's actually what you want - make this decision for each single post that would be modified by an import process; or do you want the _whole_ import process to run/not run?

Comment: _"But the problem is that I have to check a custom_field in each import to get a number which will be used in the query to check if the import should be run or not."_ - not really clear what you mean by that either; what custom field, stored where? On a specific post, on the current post to update?

Comment: @CBroe the whole import should run or be skipped. The custom field is in the import template. Each import has a custom field where the id of the customer is stored hardcoded (it is not coming from the xml). So by using the import_id I quess I have to retrieve this custom field...

Comment: _"the whole import should run or be skipped"_ - then you should rather be using the `pmxi_before_xml_import` hook, https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/code-snippets/#only-continue-import-if-import-file-contains-records

Comment: @CBroe yes but how I can get the custom field from the import using the import_id in pmxi_before_xml_import ?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by "The custom field is in the import template." to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe you can check here, maybe it helps:
https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/theme-plugin-fields/

Comment: So you are talking about a value coming from the data you are actually trying to import? Not sure if you can easily access that in this early hook already; the example they give determines the number of records that would get imported, by checking `$import->count < 100` - not sure if $import contains more useful info based on the actual data at this point. If you want to try it using your post update hook above (assuming the value is set for every record to import?), you'd have to check the contents of `$xml_node`, that should be the "input data" the post will be created from.

Comment: @CBroe well the value is hardcoded not coming from the xml that I am trying to import. Its like the address_value in the first field of the documentation page I ve sent you. It is stored in the database but as serialized array.

Comment: It is probably possible to read the field configuration for an import somehow, but I don't know any details. But the `$xml_node` in the above hook should contain the static field value the same way it does the dynamic ones, so I guess you could "cancel" the import for each individual post that way.

Comment: @CBroe thank you very much for your help! if you want add it as a solution in order to accept it